# Cross validation is very slow in Grid search (libsvm)

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, libsvm

I am using libsvm on 62 classes with 2000 samples each. The problem is i wanted to optimize my parameters using grid search. i set the range to be `C=[0.0313,0.125,0.5,2,8]` and `gamma=[0.0313,0.125,0.5,2,8]` with 5-folds. the crossvalition does not finish at the first two parameters of each. Is there a faster way to do the optimization? Can i reduce the number of folds to 3 for instance? The number of iterations written keeps playing in `(1629,1630,1627)` range  I don't know if that is related

optimization finished,

`#iter = 1629 nu = 0.997175 obj = -81.734944, rho = -0.113838 nSV = 3250, nBSV = 3247`

Answer (score 0):

This is simply expensive task to find a good model. Lets do some calculations:

`62 classes x 5 folds x 4 values of C x 4 values of Gamma = 4960 SVMs`

You can always reduce the number of folds, which will decrease the quality of the search, but will reduce the whole amount of trained SVMs of about `40%`.

The most expensive part is the fact, that SVM is not well suited for multi label classification. It needs to train at least `O(log n)` models (in the error correcting code scenario), `O(n)` (in libsvm one-vs-all) to even `O(n^2)` (in one-vs-one scenario, which achieves the best results).

Maybe it would be more valuable to switch to some fast multilabel model? Like for example some ELM (Extreme Learning Machine)?